# MapView custom pins not displaying details when clicked

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

I am trying to display the results of an array of places' names on a MapView. Using regular pins is not an issue: they display normally, and when clicked, the detail cell appears with the name of the place.

```
for var t = 0;t<self.parties2.count;++t {                                    
    var placeLatitude:CLLocationDegrees = self.parties2[t].latitude
    var placeLongitude:CLLocationDegrees = self.parties2[t].longitude
    var placeLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(placeLatitude, placeLongitude)
    var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = placeLocation
    annotation.title = self.parties2[t].name
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Then I changed the aspect of the pin with this function:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    let identifier = "pin"
    var view: MKAnnotationView
    view = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
    var image = UIImage(named: "symbol.png")
    image = self.imageResize(image!, sizeChange: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
    view.image = image

    return view
}
```

(I resize the pin image with the imageResize function)

This function succeeds in changing the aspect of the pin: it indeed becomes the desired image. However, clicking these images does not display the details anymore.

Answer (score 2):

OK I just needed to add pinView.canShowCallout = true to my code, I assumed it was true by default since it is not necessary with the original pin.